# Create custom exception or use existing

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

I have a function:

```
def f(x):

    if x == 'dog':
        print('ok')
    elif x == 'cat':
        print('ok')
    else:
        raise MyException('Not an x i would expect')
```

I m adding an exception in case one day i change whatever supplies `x` to `f()` and forget to fix `f()`, so that i can easily find the problem.

1. Is this the wrong way to "remember" to change `f()` when needed?

Secondly, `f()` is a part of another function that might get a decorator that handles certain exceptions:

```
@an_exception_handler
def g(x):
    f(x)
    return 1000
```

I don't want `@an_exception_handler` to accidentally handle `MyException` (if `MyException` is child of `ValueError` for example, and `@an_exception_handler` handles `ValueError`).

2. Should `MyException` be a custom exception, or use an existing rarely occurring exception?

Comment: Creating your own exceptions is fine, especially if you want it to be handled explicitly as distinct from common built-in exceptions. Don't use an obscure exception just because it might not be handled as common exceptions might be, that'd be self-defeating and confusing.

Comment: There are certain standard exceptions which rarely get caught by callers, because they are usually clear indications of errors in their code. Things like `IndexError`. If one of them is a match for what you are wanting to flag, use it to conform to DRY, otherwise create your own. In this case either `TypeError` or `ValueError` would probably be appropriate.

Comment: This is the sort of situation that `assert` is meant for, since you want the program to print an error message for the developer & abort if `f()` gets an arg that it should _never_ get. Of course, assertions should not be active in production code, but they can be useful during development.

Comment: I would use `ValueError` here since this is exactly what `ValueError` is for. I would **not** use an assertion unless this function is only used internally and you are sure that (barring any programming errors) this function will only be called with the correct values.

Comment: @PM2Ring `assert` sounds tempting, but unfortunately i ll probably need such exceptions to be raised during runtime of optimized code too, so that i can record them.

Comment: @Matt: I agree that in production code `ValueError` is a good fit. But in development code, if you want a message that essentially says" Hey, you need to update `f()` to conform with the changed program specs", then an assertion is appropriate. So I think we agree. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you really don't want to make `MyException` a subclass of `ValueError` you should definitely make your own exception class, except you find another exception class that describes the exception equally good.

To be honest, your way of handling "all `ValueError`s but this one" (and by concept this definitely is a `ValueError`) feels a bit inconsidtent. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

As PM 2Ring pointed out in his comment, an assertion would also be a good way to go. Probably better than another exception.